# "möglichst schnell" and "schnellstmöglich"

Tags: difference, adjective

`As quickly as possible` can be translate as

> möglichst schnell

or

> schnellstmöglich

Is there any difference between the two versions? What other adjectives have the second version (i.e., _________stmöglich)?

Comment: You can actually very easily look for "all" the words with certain ending ([see this answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/10893/1691) for some basic but quite complete search, and see one of knut's answers [which I now cannot find], were he wrote code  to do it).

Comment: @c.p. Dou you mean this one: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/7340/974 ?

Comment: @knut Ja genau, die Antwort :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`möglichst schnell` has a more friendly touch: Please make it as fast if possible. You could use this, if you need it fast, but you have no authority to force it.

`schnellstmöglich` expresses more urgency: Make it as fast as possible! This could be used by your boss if he needs it urgent.

---

For your second question: 
I selected a list of `~stmöglich` from a text database and get this result (in bold my subjective selection of common words):

- **bestmöglich**
- breitestmöglich
- **brutalstmöglich**
- ehestmöglich
- engstmöglich
- **frühestmöglich**
- geringstmöglich
- höchstmöglich
- kleinstmöglich
- kürzestmöglich
- niedrigstmöglich
- **nächstmöglich**
- raschestmöglich
- schlechtestmöglich
- schlimmstmöglich
- schnellstmöglich
- schwerstmöglich
- strengstmöglich
- stärkstmögliche
- weitestmöglich

Comment: Maybe you could add a part about those ones that can be used as an adjective... like "schlimmstmöglich" ... because in these cases, we cannot take them apart.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of phrasing arises from the superlative form of an adjective.

> infinitive, comparative, superlative
>   good, better, best e.g.

are the three states an adjective can have.

In this case:

> schnell, schneller, am schnellsten

By swapping these to phrasings, as you did, the superlative state just gets passed/swapped from one word to the other

> schnell**st**möglich *or* möglich**st** schnell

Another phrase which might be heard is: *als bald möglich* or *möglichst bald*
(I think my father uses this from time to time :) )

Answer (score 2):

**schnellstmöglich** means "as fast as possible"

while

**möglichst schnell** means "fast, if possible"

therefore, as knut already said, "möglichst schnell" is not as urgent as "schnellstmöglich" and more polite in that context.