# Wie kann man die Bedeutung von Verben mit Vorsilben ableiten?

Tags: verb, prefix

Es gibt richtig viele Verben, die Vorsilben haben. 
Z. B. das Verb *sehen* kann mit verschiedenen Vorsilben kombiniert werden:

1. ***ab***sehen
2. ***an***sehen
3. ***aus***sehen
4. ***be***sehen
5. ***durch***sehen
6. ***ein***sehen
7. ***ver***sehen
8. ***vor***sehen

Es gibt auch mehr Vorsilben, die mit anderen Verben kommen, z. B.: *über, zer, unter, ab, an, zu, auf, ...*

Jetzt stellt sich mir die Frage: **Wie kann man das alles lernen? Gibt es eine bestimmte Regel?** Ich weiß zum Beispiel, dass *ver* meistens bedeutet, dass etwas falsch geschieht, z. B.: *verlaufen, verschreiben* oder *verschlafen.* Gibt es ähnliche Regeln für andere Vorsilben?

Comment: Es gibt auch Verben, die nur mit Vorsilbe existieren: verlieren, vermuten

Comment: Bei abtrennbaren Vorsilben (ab, an, aus, durch, vor, hinein usw.) kann man sich zumindest die Grundbedeutung meistens durch abtrennen erschließen, wenn auch oft nur im übertragenen Sinn – z.B. *untersuchen* = einer Sache auf den Grund gehen. Bei nicht abtrennbaren Vorsilben geht selbst das leider nicht, da bleibem einem nur vage Merkhilfen wie *ver+* →falsch, oder mehr als üblich, oder *zer-* →unwiederbringlich. Für die Vorsilbe *be-* gibt es überhaupt keine Merkhilfe. Am besten man lernt umgekehrt jedes Verb einzeln und freut sich über die Eselsbrücke, dass es ein Grundverb gibt.

Comment: @Abdulla: Du hast **ver**lieben vergessen ;)

Comment: Danke @tink und **sich verlieben** heißt genau das Gegenteil von **verlieben** ;)

Comment: @Abdullahawara: Das Verb »verlieben« kann man nur reflexiv verwenden. »Verlieben« ohne »sich« gibt's nicht. Daher ist »verlieben« keineswegs das Gegenteil von irgend etwas anderem, sondern schlichtweg nur der grammatische Infinitiv, der allein (also ohne ein Reflexivpronomen) in keinem korrekten deutschen Satz vorkommen kann.

Comment: Zugehörig, allerdings kein Duplikat: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10891/is-there-a-dictionary-for-verb-meanings-with-different-prefixes/11719#11719

Comment: Die Antwort ist, es gibt sehr sehr viele (historisch gewachsene) Ausnahmen, so dass man keine Regeln aufstellen kann, sondern nur Tendenzen feststellen kann. Also => immer hübsch auswendig lernen.

Comment: Sehen kann ebenfalls mit einigen der zusätzlich erwähnten Silben kombiniert werden: übersehen, zusehen, aufsehen.

Answer (score 11):

Ich habe es gerade in meinem Kurs für Geflüchtete recht erfolgreich mit Handbewegungen versucht, die sich natürlich hier nur ungefähr beschreiben lassen:

- be-: streichende Handbewegung, man denke an "befahren, bestreichen, bemalen"
- ent-: herausziehende Handbewegung, man denke an "entkorken" und den entsprechenden "Plopp"
- er-: öffnende Handbewegung, man denke an "erblühen, erstrahlen, erkennen"
- ver-: Hände rollen übereinander, man denke an "Verlauf, verkaufen, verarbeiten, verschwinden" - es ist ein Prozess, auch dann, wenn es um einen Irrtum geht (sich verlaufen, sich verirren, sich vergaloppieren)
- wider-: Fäuste gegeneinander, man denke an "widerstreiten, widersprechen, sich widersetzen"
- zer-: die flache rechte Hand ("Karate") schlägt auf die linke Faust, man denke an "zerstören, zerschlagen, zerbrechen".

Gesten können besser als Worte das Ungefähre der Bedeutungsfelder bei diesen Vorsilben ausdrücken.

Achtung: Das alles git nur für eine von drei Kategorien von Verben mit Vorsilbe, nämlich Vorsilbe kommt nicht als Präposition vor, die Betonung liegt auf der Stammsilbe, die Vorsilbe ist folglich nicht abtrennbar, das Perfekt bzw. Partizip Perfekt wird ohne "ge-" gebildet.

Die anderen beiden Kategorien sind:

- Vorsilbe kommt als Präposition vor und ist betont: abfahren (Vorsile abtrennbar)
- Vorsilbe kommt als Präposition vor und ist unbetont: hintergehen (Vorsilbe ist nicht abtrennbar)

Sonderfall: die gleiche Vorsilbe betont und unbetont mit unterschiedler Bedeutung, berühmtestes Beispiel úmfahren vs. umfáhren
und dann noch die Verben mit zwei Vorsilben: mitverdienen, umbenennen

Comment: Da fallen mir auf Anhieb jeweils dutzende Gegenbeispiele ein: **be**sorgen, **be**füllen, sich **be**trinken, **be**raten. **ent**scheiden, **ent**wickeln, **ent**decken, **er**blinden, **er**trinken, **er**reichen. Zu *»ver«*: Bis auf wenige Ausnahmen beschreibt jedes Verb einen Prozess (*be*fahren, *ent*korken, *er*blühen usw. sind lauter Prozesse). Lediglich bei *»wieder-«* und *»zer-«* hast du recht.

Comment: Dutzende Gegenbeispiele sind nicht hilfreich, wenn jemand eine einprägsame Eselsbrücke bauen möchte, es geht schließlich nicht um eine feste Regel.

Comment: @HubertSchönast falsch ist die Einordnung von *be* nicht, aber unvollständig, soweit *be-* zu *bei* gehört und wie *an* sowohl direkten Kontakt oder seltener nur gewisse Nähe bei-schreibt. Da Präpositionen sich überschneiden und mehrdeutig sind, muss die idiomatische Bedeutung im Kontext erlernt werden. Vgl. *betrunken* vs *angetrunken*. Schönen Herrentag noch!

Comment: Die Doppeldeutigkeit ist synchron teilweise auch gar nicht mehr aufzulösen, Vgl. bspw. *beschweren* ~ *belasten*, aber *Beschwerde* ~ *Antrag*.~ *bestreiten* ~ *anfechten*. Ganz anders *angreifen* ~ *begreifen* oder *ein Feld bestellen* vs *ein Bier bestellen*.

Comment: Das ist eine geniale Idee. Wie bist du darauf gekommen?

Answer (score 5):

Das ist sehr schwer, ich würde sogar sagen, unmöglich. Als Beispiel will ich hier nur auf die Vorsilbe »***ver-***« eingehen.

Du hast in der Frage die Behauptung aufgestellt, dass die Silbe »ver-« am Beginn eines Verbs bedeuten würde, dass etwas falsch geschieht. Das trifft zwar in einigen Fällen tatsächlich zu, ist aber trotzdem eher die Ausnahme als die Regel.

Ein Beispiel:

### verlieren

> Egon wiegt zwar noch immer 180 kg, aber er hat in den letzen Wochen 15 kg abgenommen. Er will unbedingt noch mehr Gewicht **verlieren**.

Wenn jemand, der übergewichtig ist, Gewicht verliert, dann passiert genau das, was gewünscht ist. Da läuft nichts falsch.

Natürlich kann »verlieren« auch eine negative Bedeutung haben:

> Peter hat sein Handy **verloren**.

Aber das ist eben nur eine mögliche Verwendung des Verbs, und ist keine »fix eingebaute« Eigenschaft des Verbs. Es hängt eben vom Kontext ab, also davon, in welchem Satz man das Verb verwendet.

Darüber hinaus ist »verlieren« eines der Verben, die ohne die Vorsilbe »ver-« gar nicht existieren können. Das Verb »*lieren*« gibt es nicht, ebensowenig wie »*belieren*, *umlieren*, *überlieren* usw.« Es gibt einzig und allein nur »*verlieren*«.

Dasselbe gilt für ...

### vermuten

> Der Ermittler **vermutet**, dass Walter das Geld genommen hat.

Wenn ein Ermittler etwas *vermutet*, dann macht er genau das, wofür er bezahlt wird. Genau das ist sein Job. Da macht weder der Ermittler, noch sonst jemand etwas falsch. Und auch »vermuten« kann ohne »ver-« oder mit einer anderen Vorsilbe nicht existieren.

Anderes Beispiel, das in den Kommentaren zu deiner Frage erwähnt wurde:

### verlieben

> Norbert hat sich in Helmut **verliebt**.

Das Verb »verlieben« ist mit starken positiven Gefühlen besetzt. Es drückt aufflammende Zuneigung und Verlangen nach einer anderen Person aus. Das passiert zwar manchmal ungeplant, ist aber nichts, das grundsätzlich falsch laufen würde.

»Verlieben« kann übrigens im Deutschen immer nur zusammen mit einem Reflexivpronomen verwendet werden (z.B. »sich« im obigen Satz). Es ist also ein echtes reflexives Verb (so wie auch *freuen*, *wundern* oder *kümmern*). Wenn in einem Satz »verlieben« vorkommt, dann hat dieser Satz immer diese Eigenschaften:

- Der Satz ist ein Aktivsatz und kann nicht in einen Passivsatz umgewandelt werden.
- Der Satz enthält ein Reflexivpronomen das im Akkusativ steht (mich, dich, sich, uns, euch)

Das trifft nicht nur auf »*verlieben*«, sondern auf alle echten reflexiven Verben zu, mit der Einschränkung, dass einige Verben das Reflexivpronomen nicht im Akkusativ, sondern im Dativ verlangen (z.B. »merken«: »Ich merke *mir* deine Telefonnummer«).

### verkaufen

> *(freudestrahlender Verkäufer zu seinem Chef):*
>   Wir haben heute so viele Fahrräder wie noch nie **verkauft**.

Auch hier läuft nichts falsch. Der Job eines *Verkäufers* ist es Waren zu *verkaufen*. Wenn er das macht, macht er alles genau richtig.

---

Es gibt unzählige Verben, die mit »ver-« beginnen, aber keineswegs ausdrücken, dass etwas falsch läuft:

> Lisa hat sich heute mit Helga **verabredet**.
>   Der Arzt hat mir ein neues Medikament **verabreicht**.
>   Die Politiker **verabschieden** ein neues Gesetz.
>   Heinz muss die Einstellungen **verändern**.
>   Der General hat die Verlegung der Truppen zu **verantworten**.
>   Der Computer **verarbeitet** die Daten.
>   Je weiter man von der Wurzel weg ist, desto stärker **verästeln** sich die Zweige.

Das waren jetzt nur Beispiele, bei denen auf die Vorsilbe »ver-« ein Verb folgt, das mit *a* oder *ä* beginnt. Das Alphabet hat noch mehr als zwei Dutzend andere Buchstaben, da lassen sich noch hunderte andere Gegenbeispiele zu deiner These finden.

Die Beispiele, die du genannt hast um deine These zu belegen, möchte ich aber trotzdem auch noch hervorheben:

### verlaufen

Das kann natürlich bedeuten, dass man in die falsche Richtung gelaufen ist (nämlich dann, wenn es reflexiv, also mit »sich« verwendet wird):

> Hänsel und Gretel haben sich im Wald **verlaufen**.

Aber in der nicht-reflexiven Verwendung, bedeutet das Verb etwas anderes:

> Wie ist dein heutiger Tag **verlaufen**?
>   Mein Tag ist hervorragend **verlaufen**, ich habe eine Gehaltserhöhung bekommen.

Auch in diesem Beispiel lief nichts falsch.

### verschreiben

Du hast wahrscheinlich an so etwas gedacht:

> Anna hat beim Diktat einen Fehler gemacht. Sie hat sich **verschrieben**.

Aber man kann dieses Verb auch anders verwenden, und auch da läuft nichts falsch:

> Der Doktor hat mir ein neues Medikament **verschrieben**.

### verschlafen

Auch dieses Verb muss keineswegs bedeuten, dass irgend etwas falsch läuft:

> Endlich hat Susi Ferien, aber heute regnet es in Strömen. Aber wenn sie will, kann Susi ruhig den ganzen Vormittag **verschlafen**. Sie wird nichts versäumen und kann sich endlich mal vom Stress der letzten Tage erholen.

Falls Susi wirklich den ganzen Vormittag verschläft, macht sie nichts falsch. An einem verregneten Ferientag ist das völlig in Ordnung.

Comment: Siehe auch: verstehen, versorgen, verhandeln

Comment: Die Vorsilbe *ver-* hat eben zwei Bedeutungen, einen *Zustandswechsel* und erst daraus abgeleitet die *Verschlechterung eines Zustands*; Vgl. *vergolden*, *verstehen*, etc. In der Frage wurde aber nicht nach Beispielen gefragt, sondern nach einem generellen Schema, als da etwa wären prepositionale Vorsilben *vorlaufen, hinfallen*, welche wohl nicht frraglich sind. In anderen Fällen wird schon daran, dass die Vorsilbe nicht getrennt geschrieben wird, deutlich, dass die Zerlegung in einzelteile eben nicht gut funktioniert.

Answer (score 3):

... etwas spät, aber nur damit ist korrekt ist.

> vermuten
>
> anmuten
> zumuten

Letztere beide widerlegen den obigen Ansatz das vermuten nur mit der Vorsilbe "*ver*" existiert.

Um auf den durchaus schönen Text aufzubauen, der mir ansonsten tadellos erscheint, möchte ich darauf aufmerksam machen, dass es sich bei "*anmuten*" und "*zumuten*" ebenfalls um Verben handelt, die wie "*verlieben*" nur zusammen mit einem Reflexivronom existieren.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, dass es von Fall zu Fall unterschiedlich einfach bis hin zu unmöglich ist, die Bedeutung aus der Vorsilbe direkt abzuleiten.

Man denke nur an *(einen Pylon) umfahren* vs. *(ein Hindernis) umfahren* - einmal mit Betonung auf *um*, einmal mit Betonung auf *fahren* ergibt sich bei gleicher Vorsilbe völlig unterschiedliche Bedeutung.

Comment: Deine beiden Beispiele sind aber durchaus systematisch und daher kein Beispiel dafür, dass man die Bedeutung nicht ableiten kann.