# Function/meaning of verb prefixes

Tags: meaning, verb, prefix

I am learning German, and I am interested to understand the grammatical function of the prefixes *ein, be, ver, aus, ab,* etc. that are used before a verb and what are they supposed to do with the verb. For example, in a discussion with a friend he told me that somehow *be-* is supposed to transform a verb referring to one object into a verb referring to two objects. For example:

> *greifen* = grab/keep something
>   *be-greifen* = understand = grab something and put it somewhere (into my mind)

I would be very very pleased if someone gave me a link of a small pdf, a reference to book chapter or something to begin with. Because in this way the vast amount of verbs with these prefixes in front, would roughly break down into some categories and *a priori* would be more understandable.

Comment: They are not prepositions (i.e. distinct words) but prefixes (syllables that are a part of the word)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wie kann man die Bedeutung von Verben mit Vorsilben ableiten?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/wie-kann-man-die-bedeutung-von-verben-mit-vorsilben-ableiten)

Comment: If you have luck, also your first language has such prefixes. In this case, you may find significant parallelism between that and German, and you have to learn only the difference. If not, then I think you could learn these Verbs (which is the majority of the actually said verbs) with their prefixes together.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the question Hubert mentions because the languages are different!

Answer (score 5):

### grammatical function

There are two classes of such prefixes:

- **Vorsilben**

  - **be**fallen

    > Der Parasit wird den Wirt **be**fallen.
    >   Der Parasit **be**fällt den Wirt.
  - **ent**fallen

    > Das ist mir **ent**fallen.
    >   Das **ent**fällt mir.
  - **miss**fallen

    > Dein Verhalten hat mir **miss**fallen.
    >   Dein Verhalten **miss**fällt mir.
  - **ver**fallen

    > Diese Burg ist **ver**fallen.
    >   Diese Burg **ver**fällt.
  - **zer**fallen

    > Das Puzzle wird bald in seine Einzelteile **zer**fallen.
    >   Das Puzzle **zer**fällt in seine Einzelteile.
- **Verbzusätze**

  - **auf**fallen

    > Ihr Kleid wird dir **auf**fallen.
    >   Ihr Kleid fällt dir **auf**.
  - **ein**fallen

    > Das wird mir schon noch **ein**fallen.
    >   Das fällt mir **ein**.
  - **an**fallen

    > Der Hund wird den Briefträger **an**fallen.
    >   Der Hund fällt den Briefträger **an**.

The most important difference:

If it is a *Vorsilbe*, then it is part of the word, that always is there. It never leaves the core of the word.

If it is a *Verbzusatz*, then it is sometimes a prefix and sometimes a distinct word. Verbs that have such *Verbzusätze* are called *»trennbare Verben«* (*separable verbs*)

---

### semantic function

It is not so easy to generalize the semantic function (i.e. meaning) of those *Vorsilben* and *Verbzusätze*. I already discussed this in an [answer to another question](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34072/1487), based on the example *»ver-«*.

The best way is not to focus on those suffixes. Try to understand *missfallen, verfallen, umfallen, einfallen, ...* as distinct verbs, that have no connection, and learn them separately. Also try to learn *verfallen, verlieren, verschreiben, ...* as separate verbs without any semantic connection.

Comment: Die Empfehlung, keinerlei Zusammenhang zwischen ein-, be-, ver-, aus- sowie abgreifen und greifen zu sehen, geht viel zu weit, um mit diesem Beitrag ein Plus abgreifen zu lassen. Eine derart widersinnige Empfehlung ist nicht zu begreifen.

Comment: @userunknown: Dann bitte ich dich, in weniger als 20 Worten auf verständliche und nachvollziehbare Weise die Gemeinsamkeit von *gefallen* und *verfallen* z.B. in »Das Haus **gefällt** mir, schade, dass es **verfällt.**« zu beschreiben. Mit demselben Wortstamm werden ja auch Nomen gebildet, vielleicht gelingt es dir, auch **Zufall** und **Beifall** in deine Beschreibung einfließen zu lassen.

Comment: Ist es denn der selbe Wortstamm oder ist es nur eine Zeichenkettenkongruenz? Entweder sie haben eine Verbindung oder nicht -  Du widersprichst Dir da gerade selbst. Und nein, ich habe die Fragestellung nicht aufgeworfen, also bin ich nicht in der Bringpflicht, zumal nicht in weniger als 20 Wörtern - das soll wohl ein Witz sein? Du schreibst ja selbst selten weniger als 4 Bildschirmseiten.

Comment: *The best way is not to focus on those **suffixes***: hier wohl eher *prefixes* oder allgemein *affixes*

Answer (score 4):

Yes, prefixes such "aus", "be", "ver", etc. modify the meaning of verbs they precede in somewhat predictable ways.

However as a beginner the most important distinction to know is when a prefix indicates a phrasal verb or not.

Phrasal verbs are split, meaning the prefix is separated from the verb:

> Ich stehe normalerweise um 6 Uhr **auf**.

With non-phrasal verbs the prefix stays attached to the verb.

Here is a worksheet that provides a very good introduction to separable and inseparable prefixes. It also explains what each prefix means and how it influences the meaning of the verb it's attached to.

[Verb prefixes worksheet](http://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/sepinsepprefixexpl.html)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers were focusing on separable vs. inseparable prefixes, which don’t think was what the question was getting at, which was whether there is a consistent way of finding the meaning of a verb from the prefix and the stem. In my experience there are three possible situations:

1. The verb and the prefix+verb have virtually the same meaning and only a native speaker can really understand the shades of meaning or differences in usage to know which to use in a given situation; certainly there appears to be no difference in the dictionary meanings. An example is *bewahren* vs. *aufbewahren* which both, according to Wiktionary, mean *to keep, to preserve*. Google translate gives the same translation to “Ich bewahre meine Kleidung im Schrank auf” and “Ich bewahre meine Kleidung im Schrank”, namely “I keep my clothes in the closet”. Maybe one of those two choices seems odd or awkward to a native speaker, but for practical purposes if you’re trying to understand the sentence they are pretty much the same.
2. The verb and the prefix+verb have meanings that are substantially different can’t be inferred from one another. An example of this case is *bauen* vs. *anbauen* which mean, respectively, *to build* and *to plant*. (There is another meaning for *anbauen*, *to build onto*, but I’m ignoring that for the moment.) There’s no way to derive *to plant* from *to onbuild* so this is a case where you just have to memorize the different meanings individually.
3. The meaning of the prefix+verb can be derived, or at least with some imagination  be linked, to the meanings of the prefix and the verb. An example of this case is *hören*, *to hear* and *anhören*, *to listen*. With some mental gymnastics one can imagine how *to at-hear* might be interpreted as *to listen*, and this might be useful as either a mnemonic or as an aid to finding the meaning of the word with some additional context. Sometimes different prefixes have the same effect by the dictionary meanings, for example *anhören* and *zuhören* both mean *to listen*, so again there are subtleties that a student is bound to miss.

So I’d say instead of looking for a simple chart that will explain everything on one page, just be sure to check the etymology whenever you look up a word, and for online dictionaries see if there are links for related or derived words; it’s always nice to learn three or four words for the price of one. Just make sure to use the same caution you’d use with cognates; they can be shortcuts but they can also be *false friends* that will steer you the the wrong direction.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. I disagree to take google translate as a reference for a translation (example). While many humans are used to train the algorithm it is still an algorithm. And as your answer points out: there is not much algorithm to be used here.

Comment: @Shegit Brahm It's true Google translate doesn't replace a human translator since (for one thing) it misses many of the subtleties of natural language. I wasn't using it as a reference though, but as an example of how the two sentences seem to mean the same thing if you're not a native speaker or very fluent in the language. To me one of the most difficult aspects of studying a foreign language is knowing which of several synonymous words to use in a given situation. Google translate doesn't really help with that.

Answer (score 0):

### be-

**"*be-* makes a verb transitive"**

This is the general rule. The examle "greifen" can show what is  meant. It is a complicated, but typical case.

> ? Ich greife einen Stein.

Duden has this first example, under the first meaning which is "1. ergreifen". I did not even know you can use it transitively...but it is rare. Duden's next example is reflexive "sich  greifen." All these uses are more common with pure "greifen":

```
Ich greife mir einen Stein.   (to get equipped with) 
Ich greife nach einem Stein.  (to reach for) 
Ich ergreife einen Stein.     (to pick up)
```

"greifen nach etw." is not the same as "etw. ergreifen", both grammatically and semantically.

While the 3 modifications above keep the original meaning, the `be-` is used to make a semantic shift - from things to ideas, from hand to mind.

Now you can say:

```
Das begreife ich.
Das habe ich begriffen.
```

Transitive (but not with hands!), and it does not even matter if present or past tense.

The constant - what you get for free - is the "-griffen", the grammtical form.

Similar patterns ban be formed with:

```
kommen - bekommen (Der Sommer kommt / Wir bekommen Sommer...i.e. if something comes to you, you recieve it. See re-capere. Also be-come.)
gehen  - begehen  (begehen = "officially" walk (on) or celebrate, or commit) 
halten - behalten 
nehmen - sich benehmen (s. benehmen = to be-have)
rühren - berühren (move/stir vs. touch)
stehen - bestehen (stand vs. exist)
```

`be-` can also turn nouns and adjectives into verbs:

```
schön - etw. beschönigen (to pretty up sth.) 
Gnade - jmdn. begnadigen
```

---

So why should an English speaker say:

> **Com-pris** in French means **under-stood**, I **com-prehend**. But what does
>   **ver-standen** mean?